# A Milk spilled to my PC, is it stil possible to save it?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu, water-damage

Got an accident this morning, my daughter glass of milk spill to my tower PC. As soon as it happen I disconnect the plug and open up my tower case. Trace of milk can be seen in my CPU, GPU card and my motherboard. I have tried to clean it using cotton bud. in detail:

- in CPU socket I can find trace of milk and tried using cotton bud to wipe the milk off and below CPU has some milk.
- in GPU behind it has some trace of milk, clean it using cotton bud. not trace in GPU socket.
- in motherboard has some dripping, clean it using cotton bud.

as right now I have dismantle my PC and all of its hardware and wrap it with tissue and put it in safe place. After all of this is there anything else I should have done to save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you started off in the right direction...

Putting it in rice & hoping for the best is about the worst thing you can do.
Your first enemy on a spill is short-circuiting.
Your real enemy sneaks up behind - corrosion.

Speed is of the essence.

Disconnect from any power [which you already did] Take out any batteries [including the CMOS battery].

Mop as much up as you can *quickly*.

Strip it down as far as you possibly can - including CPU cooler & GPU casing so you can get in as far as possible.

Spray down with isopropyl alcohol [in spray form it's sold as contact cleaner, expect to need a whole can] to rinse away any residue. Use a soft brush if you're getting dust bunnies or any visible residue too [milk may rapidly congeal near hot components].

Once you've got it cleaned down, then leave it disassembled for a day to make sure it's dry - the isopropyl will chase out water, but then may get stuck in tiny areas under the CPU etc so let it dry at least 24h.

One last point - if any liquid got into the PSU itself, you're far safer to discard it & replace. 120/240v is not fun to play with, & in relative terms a PSU is a cheap component.

Make something appetising to go with the rice you saved ;)

Comment: hi, thank your for your reply, for alcohol and rice for now is quite hard to find (due to quarantine). Is using water mixed with soap or chlorine based liquid a good idea to substitute alcohol?

Comment: I wouldn't risk it. Isopropyl will not damage anything further. It will contain just enough water to aid dilution of anything not directly soluble in alcohol alone, but little enough to not affect drying times. Pure, distilled water will technically clean almost as well, but residue & drying time become your enemies; any contaminant including soap will undo any good the water alone had managed, & long drying times, especially in tight enclosed areas like under the CPU will leave you very prone to corrosion.

Comment: You can get contact cleaner online, DIY stores & eBay etc. You can get pure isopropyl from a chemist/drug store, though they will certainly ask what you want it for.

Comment: thanks, I have bought contact cleaner and it is on delivery, will update later after I try to clean using contact cleaner.

Comment: Excellent news. Glad it worked for you :)