# Laptop battery still charging but won’t turn on after sitting in a case that had water dripping on it over the weekend

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, water-damage

I left my computer at home for the weekend and when I got back a water pipe in the ceiling had broke and was dripping over my laptop which was inside of a cover. The cover was completely wet but the laptop inside wasn't.

I even open it up completely and didn't see major water problem. So naturally I tried to turn it on but it didn't. So then I let it dry for 2 days with some rice and decided it was ready to turn on.

Sadly it didn’t but the weird thing is that the battery is charging correctly according to the power light. So I’m here to see if someone has any idea if this is a sign that the computer might not be dead or it is just that the battery part didn’t get damaged but everything else did.

Also the computer was in sleep mode and when I try to turn it on the power button and the power status light blink slowly.

Comment: Putting it in rice & hoping for the best is about the worst possible thing you can do. See https://superuser.com/a/1538101/347380 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Water seeps around corners and edges, so you likely had water get into the laptop.
2. Make sure the laptop is OFF, remove the battery, plug in the AC adapter. Turn the laptop ON.  Does it turn ON.

It appears the laptop has been damaged and needs to be serviced, if that is feasible. Since the machine was suspended, there is some power inside and water can damage electronics in this situation.

Comment: I know water seeps in but because it was all dry i though maybe no water damage. Also don't now how long did it stayed inside a wet cover. I did disconnect the battery and it wont turn on but will light the power button and power status light for some time.

Comment: The machine was damaged and you need to have it serviced as I suggested.  There is some bit of warmth in a suspended machine which will dry out water, but suspend means some power inside and that is likely what was damaged.

Comment: one last question. Does trying to turn it on will increase the damage?

Comment: That depends on the damage inside.  We cannot tell from here whether turning it on increases the damage or not.

Comment: Ok at least is not a solid yes

Comment: And note that the machine got wet with dirty water, not clean water.  That makes it much more likely that when it dried it left behind deposits--which can be electrically conductive.  Even if nothing got fried by turning it on before it was utterly dry there might be problems.  I've dealt with a laptop that suffered water/inappropriate turn on/dry/doesn't work--when I got it open I found deposits all over the main board.  Pulled the drive for it's data, no point in fixing the machine.