# I spilled tea on my laptop and now my touchpad isn't working

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, water-damage

I was sitting in my bed and left my computer to the side, and I accidentally knocked over a cup of tea I was drinking earlier, I'm pretty sure everything on my computer works except the touchpad. The touchpad won't work; it won't move my mouse or click on anything! My computer is an HP Laptop and Windows 10 and is Model 14-cf0006dx.

Comment: You cannot fix this touchpad while installed in the machine. Get the service manual from HP, remove the battery, then remove the keyboard from the machine, then carefully rinse the touchpad with clear clean water. Allow to dry overnight and then (ensure dry) install the keyboard, then the battery, then try. Most likely you will have to replace the keyboard.

Comment: Don't treat tea like you'd treat water - it is considerably worse. See https://superuser.com/a/1538101/347380 Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a large amount of luck, maybe it could fix by itself, when the remaining water residue dries out.

You really shouldn't power on the device with water in it, since it can do even more damage.

Assuming nothing else got damaged by water, you can open up your laptop and clean up your touchpad. If it still doesn't work, you can replace it.

Otherwise, if you don't feel up to it, try to find some local computer repair shop.

Comment: Good call telling them not to power it up. I would add remove the battery if possible, electrolysis can still happen with it in. +1

Comment: It wasn't water, it was tea. The single worst thing to do is just hope it dries out & nothing else went wrong. Removing the power is a good thing, though.